# What's kind of document that allow String turn to speaking (Siri speaking, not human speaking)

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I am a comic developer, however, I am deaf iOS developer. I don't need to hiring hearing but i know iOS has feature to select all sentence to speak like that. I need any idea whats called and code sample to make a speak whenever the String comes into speaking like that in Swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for “speech synthesis”, also called “text-to-speech” (TTS for short).

Apple provides speech synthesis in the AVFoundation framework.

- [Speech Synthesis documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/speech_synthesis)
- [AVSpeechSynthesizer: Making iOS Talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/236/)
- [Create a seamless speech experience in your apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10022)

Apple's accessibility system also provides speech synthesis. This feature is called VoiceOver.

- [UIAccessibilityReadingContent protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityreadingcontent/)
- [Creating an Accessible Reading Experience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/248)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check it out, but I will give an update if I have some troubleshooting with that speech synthesis code.